# Raspberry shows marquee jerkily when I use jquery slideshow

Tags: html, jquery, slideshow, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I utilise a [jquery image slideshow](http://responsiveslides.com/) and a scrolling text showed with this marquee code

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="5">my text</marquee>
```

When I see my page from my pc all is correctly showed, but if I go to this page from my raspberry (with raspbian installed) or if I emulate raspbian with qemu the scrolling text is showe jerkily.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi is a slow computer. Don't expect it to render JavaScript animations smoothly.

Comment: Ok, but the JS animation correctly works alone. It doesn't correctly works only if I also show marquee text.